# How to change material propery based on color?

Tags: materials, shaders

I have this model from MagicaVoxel

[image]

Imagine I want the white petals to have `metallic = 1` and `roughness = 0`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to apply math filters to the Hue of the color.  White has a near zero hue:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:
[image]

1 - color is 0 for white (if you are using a color other than white anywhere, check clamp in the Subtract node). Note that the roughness will be a number around 0.3 for the green parts.
Separate color splits the color info into its channels, since the 2. petal is green, red is 0, while it's 1 for the white part.
This is just an example of how to separate white and pure green (or at least no red). If the colors are mixed, for example: 0.1, 0.5, 1, you'll need to get a bit more creative, like using the threshold function of the math node to get it right.

Comment: You'r answer is right but I consider @james_t simplier, so I select his answer. Thanks!

Comment: fair enough, thanks